# using a for loop but ignoring the first item?

Tags: python, for-loop, character-encoding

I have a small problem. I have this piece of code in Python (taken from a larger script):

```
for line in open(trainFile):
  for token,tag in [x.rsplit('/',1) for x in line.split()]:
    tokenTagCount[(token,tag)] += 1
    tags[tag] += 1
    listOfTags.append(tag)
```

The trainFile contains words and tags for Danish, but that's not the issue. The problem is this: because the file is in Danish, I have to include `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-` at the first line to properly show the characters in Python. However, my for loop ("for line in open...") should ignore this first line about coding and start running at the second line of the trainFile, where the actual data begin. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `trainFile` a Python script? If so, why not just `import` it? If not, why do you need a `coding:` line on top?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. It is just a file with data, so I don't think it is a Python file? I need the coding to get the Danish characters to show up correctly in the Python shell.

Comment: Usually, `# -*- coding:` lines are only applied to Python scripts. If you are editing the file using the Python IDE, I guess it makes sense to add a coding line (if only for the editor's sake), though it might also be easier to edit it in some other text editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can skip the first line:

```
with open(trainFile) as f:
    next(f)  # discard the first line
    for line in f:
        # deal with the rest.
```

A better option might be to skip lines that start with `#`:

```
with open(trainFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        # deal with the rest.
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response! However, I now realised I asked the wrong question. The first line indeed gets ignored now, but this means that the coding doesn't work anymore, which is not what I was aiming for of course. Would you know of a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
f=open(trainFile)
f.readline()
for line in f.readlines():
     ........
```

Answer (score 1):

You could enumerate the lines as you read them from a file. For example:

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(trainFile)):
    if i != 0:
        # do stuff
```